# Is a per project wrapper script for cmake-gui the right way to make the source and build directories local per project instead of global?

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm building two closely related projects from source for Windows, and both of them are configured with CMake.

When I use CMake with two projects, the behaviour that I get is that the source and build directories for cmake-gui are global. First, I run cmake-gui in directory A to configure project A and set the source and build directories to those for project A. Then when I run cmake-gui in directory B to configure project B, cmake-gui remembers the source and build directories for project A, and I have to manually change them to the correct directories for project B. And when I go back to directory A to make changes to project A, cmake-gui remembers the source and build directories for project B, and I have to manually change them again back to the correct directories for project A.

That's not the behaviour that I want. I would prefer cmake-gui to remember the source and build directories for project A when I run it in directory A and to remember the source and build directories for project B when I run it in directory B. I can get that behaviour by wrapping cmake-gui in a script that sets the source and build directories using the -S and -B command line options. In this case, the source and build directories for each project have the same paths relative to their project directories so I can use an identical script for both projects:

```
@ECHO OFF
start "" cmake-gui -S . -B .\build
```

This passes the "does it work?" test - I get the behaviour that I want - but CMake isn't a tool that I know very well, and I suspect that there might be a better way that I've overlooked.

Is a per project wrapper script really the right way to do this?